# Flutter class in class to json decode

Tags: json, flutter, class, dart

How can I use class in class value?

For example I have a class like below.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Product {
  final String productId;
  final String productName;
  final String productImageUrl;
  final String productCategory;

  Product(
      {required this.productId,
      required this.productName,
      required this.productImageUrl,
      required this.productCategory});

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      productId: json['productId'],
      productName: json['productName'],
      productImageUrl: json['productImageUrl'],
      productCategory: json['productCategory'],
    );
  }
  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Product product) => {
        'productId': product.productId,
        'productName': product.productName,
        'productImageUrl': product.productImageUrl,
        'productCategory': product.productCategory,
      };

  static String encode(List<Product> products) => json.encode(
        products
            .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((product) => Product.toMap(product))
            .toList(),
      );

  static List<Product> decode(String products) =>
      (json.decode(products) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<Product>((item) => Product.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
}
```

And I can use encode and decode like this.

Encode:

```
final String encodedData = Product.encode([
          Product(
              productId: "1",
              productName: "Americano",
              productImageUrl: "assets/americano.jpeg",
              productCategory: "Warm"),
          Product(
              productId: "2",
              productName: "Latte",
              productImageUrl: "assets/americano.jpeg",
              productCategory: "Cold"),
        ]);
```

Decode:

```
    List<Product> products;

    products = Product.decode(encodedData);
```

Now here is my  question. If I want to use this product class like list in another class. How can I write encode, decode and fromJson methods? Can you help me? And please give me example usages.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:orderapp/models/product.dart';

class Bill {
  final String billNo;
  final String billNumber;
  final String tableNo;
  final String orderDateTime;
  final String orderWaiter;
  final List<Product> products;

  Bill({
    required this.billNo,
    required this.billNumber,
    required this.tableNo,
    required this.orderDateTime,
    required this.orderWaiter,
    required this.products,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data class with JSON decoder and encoder support.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Product {
  final String productId;
  final String productName;
  final String productImageUrl;
  final String productCategory;

  Product({
    required this.productId,
    required this.productName,
    required this.productImageUrl,
    required this.productCategory,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'productId': productId,
        'productName': productName,
        'productImageUrl': productImageUrl,
        'productCategory': productCategory,
      };

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Product(
        productId: map['productId'] as String,
        productName: map['productName'] as String,
        productImageUrl: map['productImageUrl'] as String,
        productCategory: map['productCategory'] as String,
      );

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Product.fromJson(String source) {
    return Product.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to write encode, decode, fromJson methods for Bill class. Not product class. Product class has these methods. And it's working.

Comment: But you can do the same with the `Bill`class like in the `Product` class in my example. Or I do not understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem. I will store the Product object in Bill objects like json string. Then I will parse it.